# How can I prevent from filling this object with a undefined?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This happens when `level` starts with the value undefined.

This code works fine in JavaScript but when I am using TypeScript it doesn't work.

```
interface Find {
    level?: string;
}

let find: Find = {};

if (!!level) {
     find.level = level;
}
```

Final value of find:

```
{"level":"undefined"}
```

Instead of just:

```
{}
```

Comment: TypeScript doesn't change the code's behavior (or not much). Undefined values are not supposed to appear at all. How do you get your "final value" print? There's nothing about this print in your code.

Comment: Considering `!!level`, any string value including `'undefined'` will be evaluated to true in your condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the value:

```
{"level":"undefined"}
```

If it was `undefined` you would see:

```
{"level":undefined}
```

What you actually have is the string `"undefined"`.

## Fix

```
interface Find {
    level?: string;
}

let find: Find = {};

if (!!level && level !== "undefined") {
     find.level = level;
}
```

And now you will get `{}`.

## More

TypeScript does not change JavaScript runtime behaviour.